# HaxeFlixel with Flashdevelop - how to enable debugger ?

Tags: flashdevelop, haxe, haxeflixel

Im asking it here since i couldn find any suitable answer on net.Im begginer with all this Haxe and FlashDevelop stuff.

So : I started working on games with HaxeFlixel with FlashDevelop. And currently I don't have debug option enabled. I was looking for answers all over net but I didn't get answer. Is there something like step by step how to set debugger ? How can i enable debugger ? It really bother me because so far i found HaxeFlixel really suitable for me.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "debugger"? I think both flashdevelop and haxeflixel provide something that is called "debugger"

Comment: okay then... how can i debug games in flashdevelop with haxeflixel ? Because normally when im using for example XNA and raise breakpoint, things usually work fine.

Comment: You can set a breakpoint by clicking left of the line number in FD, a red dot should appear. You might need to start the debugger manually via Debug -> Start Remote Session if this doesn't work. Note that the debugger is only for the flash target (there's one in the works for hxcpp builds though).

Comment: okay i get error. It says : Debugger startup error. Error details: net.sf.jni4net.jni.JNIException: JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set

Comment: You need appropriately installed and bound (via environment variables)  version of Java Runtime Environment to use Flash Player debugger in Flash Develop. FD installer warns about this. Alternatively, while building for HTML5, you can use browser-specific JavaScript debugger - some browsers will also pick up "source maps", allowing you to interact with Haxe code instead of resulting JavaScript.

Comment: okay i will try to reinstall jre and set it right somehow. By enviroment variables you mean this JAVA_HOME variable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by debugger you mean the built in haxeflixel console/debugger, then all that is required is you build your project in debug mode (not release) and when the game is running, press the "~" key, this will bring up the debugger:)